# Uploading a large plugin to Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: plugins, crm, large-files

For a little background, I am trying to reference our own unsigned libraries as well as some third party ones in a CRM 2011 Plugin. I am registering it to the database and using the following ILMerge method:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/11/09/how-to-reference-assemblies-from-plug-ins.aspx

After getting it all compiled I am running into a 404 error when trying to register my plugin, I found the following article but it is still not working.
http://www.ryanjones.io/2011/05/28/uploading-large-crm-2011-plugins/

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching forever and spinning my wheels trying other deployment methods I discovered there was a line in the CRM web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="33554432" />
```

Although my ilmerged dll was only 27 MB I was just getting a 404.

Increasing this value solved my issue. We have a 3rd party CRM customizer between the crm base product and what we end up with but in case anyone else ever runs into this it solved my issue.